# jQuery: select li above the active one

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, html-lists

How can I add the style `border-bottom : none;` to a `<li>` that is standing above the active `<li>`?

```
<ul>
  <li>text</li> <!--this li must get the border-bottom : none then.-->
  <li class="active">text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.active').prev('li').css('border-bottom','none');
```

Comment: You mean on hover? If so, try and combine with this: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Yeah i have it working now... but when i am outside the ul then you will see the border again!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('li.active').prev().css('border-bottom', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to use jQuery siblings(). Read this, it will most likely help you: http://api.jquery.com/siblings/